# Implementing twitter-like hashtag on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, tagging, hashtag

I'm want to implement twitter-like hashtag on my app.

Let's say I have user input to a text area "I'm coming to #london from #paris" then I want to build tag cloud of the hashtags.

I'm thinking of using acts-as-taggable-on. So I find all of my hashtags from the text in the backend, then save it to tag field.

Anyone has experience on this they would like to share? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a particular question you're struggling with?

Comment: This question really isn't clear. What part of this implementation are you struggling with?

Comment: This is interesting. I'm curious about various approaches to doing this - so far, it seems like acts-as-taggable-on is the only encouraged way. Also, is there a way to have these hashtags, but have them be like mentions on Facebook? In a post on Facebook, I could say "Good thing Danny and I went to Place X" and Danny, the name of the user, would be highlighted and linked...

Answer (score 12):

Yes, ActsAsTaggableOn should be fine. As @etang alluded to, it's a heavy gem, but it gets the job done. If you're looking for a simple way to extract tags from text, you may want to look at https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb. It has some nice regexps that may save you some time.

```
Twitter::Extractor.extract_hashtags("my #favorite #site is http://foo.com/home#boo")
```

That would return "favorite" and "site" but not "boo" (as would be expected).

Comment: For anyone else looking at this the url has moved to https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb

Comment: And has moved again to https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text, with the Ruby section here: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/rb

Answer (score 3):

For late-comers…

I have written a simple gem for precisely for this:
https://github.com/ralovely/simple_hashtag

Give feedback or contribute if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

`ActsAsTaggableOn` should work fine if you are not too worried about scaling.  It keeps track of your actual tags by `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag`, and keeps track of the many-to-many relationship to your posts by `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging`.  It also uses polymorphic association in `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging` so you can tag in different namespaces.