# How to create notification system in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, rubygems

Basically, I want to create a notification like Facebook and Stackoverflow. 
Specifically, in a Post-Comments system, when a post get commented, everyone involved (people who creates the post and who create comments, except the new commenter) gets a notification message that this post get commented.
And the notification get dismissed when people have read it.

I have tried to use **mailboxer** gem to implement it, but saddly there is no example available using its related methods, including **social_stream** itself.

Is there other way to create the Notification System?

And when I try to create it from scratch I get several problems:

```
    Model Notification
    topic_id: integer
    user_id: integer
    checked: boolean #so we can tell whether the notification is read or not
```

1. Dismissing the notication after being read by users

I think we just need to turn every notification messages' "checked" attribute to true after user visit the index of notification.(In the NotificationsController)

```
    def index
      @notifications=current_user.notication.all
      @notification.each do |notification|
         notification.checked = true
      end
      @notification.save!
    end
```

2.Selecting users to notify(and exclude the user making new comment)

I just have no idea in wrting queries....

3.Creating notifications

I think this should be  something like

```
    #in CommentController
    def create
      #after creating comments, creat notifications
      @users.each do |user|
        Notification.create(topic_id:@topic, user_id: user.id)
      end
    end
```

But I think this is really ugly

There is no need to anwer the 3 problems above, Any simple solution to the Notification System is preferable , thanks....

Comment: This answer may give some leads: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7049110/1096545 - It shows how to use an ActiveRecord observer for that purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are on the right path.

A slightly better notifications#index

```
def index
  @notifications = current_user.notications
  @notifications.update_all checked: true
end
```

2. Notify this users

   ```
   User.uniq.joins(:comments).where(comments: {id: @comment.post.comment_ids}).reject {|user| user == current_user }
   ```

Unique users that participated in the @comment's post comments, reject (remove from result) current_user.

3. An observer as pointed out by João Daniel, it is preferred over an after_create. This "Rails best practice" describes it pretty well: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/07/24/use-observer

Comment: A great thank to you! but.....How can I add the post.user.id into the User.uniq.joins... query? In that query only commenter get notified.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment (deleted), since we already have the post object in memory you could do `(User.uniq.joins(:comments).where(comments: {id: @comment.post.comment_ids}) | [post.user]).reject {|user| user == current_user }`. This means: Add the post.user to the array if it doesn't exist before rejecting current_user

Comment: I got another problem....What is the difference between User.uniq.joins(:comments).... and User.joins(:comments)....uniq? That is, to put 'uniq' first or later.

Comment: I'm trying something like `users=User.joins(:replies).where(:replies =>{ topic_id: topic_id}).push(topic.user).delete(sender).uniq`, the sender is the new commenter which should not be notified. But I'm not sure whether I'm using the push/delete correctly. May I ask how should I write this?

Comment: and when I use the array above, I get `undefined method `each' for #<User:0x4c772a0>`. I use `users.each do |users|` after the query to create notifications. Do you have any idea about that? thanks!

Comment: The first `uniq`, will do a DISTINCT on SQL and the second will do a `uniq` on the collection (after retrieving duplicates). `delete` will return the deleted object, you probably want `reject` instead. `b.push(a).uniq` it's equivalent to `b | [a]`. You are getting the error because `delete` is returning the deleted user, instead of the array.

Comment: After millions times of debugging... I finally get this `users= User.joins(:replies).where(replies: {id: topic.reply_ids}).push(topic.user).reject {|user| user == comment }.uniq`. It is working not, but I'm not sure its selecting the right users. Could you please help me review this code?

Comment: and I'm worrying about that what if `users` is empty(e.g, the user just comment his own topic), would the `usesrs.each` break? In my expeirence it certainly doesnt break, but I still like to aks it here.....A big thank to you, the code finally gets working

Comment: Looks good, I'm not a fan of the `uniq` at the end, but it does work. I recommend you write a test for it and if you found a corner case where it doesn't write a failing test at work until both pass, but that's for another question (when it fails). We don't want to make this discussion any longer (StackOverflow doesn't like that), so I'm glad it is working for you. For your last comment, that's an easy thing to test: `[].each { |i| puts i }`, it doesn't break, it just won't execute the content inside the block.

Answer (score 9):

there is an amazing gem called public activity ,,you can customize it as you want 
and here is a screencast about it in railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity
hope that could help you.

### Update

In my rails application I made a similar notifications system like yours to send notifications to all users 
but in index action you can user

```
current_user.notifications.update_all(:checked=>true)
```

and also to send only one notifications to the user once not several times that somebody commented on the post you can use unique_by method

```
  @comments =@commentable.comments.uniq_by {|a| a[:user_id]}
```

then you can send notifications to only users of previous comments

```
 @comments.each do |comment|
 comment.user.notifications.create!(....
 end
```

hope that could help you

Comment: I've whated this episode, but I think this is for status feed, not suitable for a notification system?